# how fill combobox with all records of a person from database based on his name on textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox, textbox

here is my code but its retrieve only last record not all

```
    SqlConnection history= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True");
                history.Open();
                SqlCommand histcmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT salary FROM persontable WHERE (Name = @name)", history);
                histcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", checkname.text);

                SqlDataReader DRhistory= histcmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (DRhistory.Read())
                {
                    combobox.Text = DRhistory.GetValue(0).ToString();


                }
                history.Close();
```

Comment: It retreives not last but first

Answer (score 3):

You need a loop if you want to get all:

```
List<string> salaryList = new List<string>();
while(DRhistory.Read())
{
    salaryList.Add(DRhistory.GetString(0));
}
```

To fill a combobox you can either add them in the loop, simpliest approach:

```
while(DRhistory.Read())
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(DRhistory.GetString(0));
}
```

or use a `BindingSource` which you can assign the list as datasource:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = salaryList;
comboBox.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: so i must change my if to while loop to create a list and then fill combo with list that's all ?

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @TimSchmelters answer:

You also need to populate the `ComboBox` with the objects in the `List`. Setting the `Text` property doesn't add the object to the `ComboBoxes` `Item` collection.

```
using(SqlConnection history= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True"))
{
     history.Open();
     SqlCommand histcmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT salary FROM persontable WHERE (Name = @name)", history);
     histcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", checkname.text);
     List<string> salaryList = new List<string>();

     using (SqlDataReader DRhistory = histcmd.ExecuteReader())
     {    
         while(DRhistory.Read())
         {
            salaryList.Add(DRhistory.GetString(0));
         }
     }

     combobox.Items.AddRange(salaryList.ToArray());

     history.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys  both of u! its worked like charm!